# PHP foreach loop with sequential numbers while displaying MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a feeling I'm going to get scolded for this but here is the question.

```
$seq_numbers = range('1', '24');
foreach($seq_numbers as $seq_number) 
{
    Bullet <?php echo $seq_number;?>  
    // (this successfully creates - Bullet 1, Bullet 2, etc. - 
        below is the problem.

    <?php echo $db_rs['bullet_($seqnumber)'];?>
}   // this one doesn't work.
```

I've tried  
with curly brackets {}

I basically have a few columns that are named same except for number at the end (bullet_1, bullet_2, bullet_3, etc.) and want to get the results using a loop.

Comment: The given code would probably give a syntax error. Using PHP tags withing PHP tags just makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is, that PHP doesn't replace variables inside strings enclosed with single quotes. You need to use `$db_rs["bullet_{$seq_number}"]` or one of those:

```
<?php
foreach ($seq_numbers as $seq_number) {
   $key = 'bullet_' . $seq_number;
   echo $db_rs[$key];
}
```

Even shorter, but a little less clear:

```
<?php
foreach ($seq_numbers as $seq_number) {
   echo $db_rs['bullet_' . $seq_number];
}
```

An entirely different approach would be to loop over the result array. Then you don't even need `$seq_numbers`. Just as an afterthought.

```
<?php
foreach ($db_rs as $key => $value) {
   if (substr($key, 0, 7) == 'bullet_') {
      echo $value;
   }
}
```

Oh...and watch out for how you spell your variables. You are using `$seq_number` and `$seqnumber`.

Comment: This is a very detailed explanation.  Now I completely understand it!  I hate asking questions where the answer is there but I don't quite understand.  Thank you!  Another tool in the belt.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $db_rs['bullet_'.$seqnumber];?>
```

Answer (score 1):

why not:

```
$db_rs['bullet_'.$seqnumber]
```

If not, what are your fields, and what does a var_dump of $db_rs look like?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$seq_numbers = range('1', '24');
foreach($seq_numbers as $seq_number) 
{
    Bullet <?php echo $seq_number;?>  
    // (this successfully creates - Bullet 1, Bullet 2, etc. - 
        below is the problem.

    <?php echo $db_rs["bullet_($seqnumber)"];?>
}   // now it works.
```